# OPTIONS 405 (Method Not Allowed) slimphp

Tags: angular, rest, cors, slim

I make rest api by slim php on share hosting but Front-end use angular so I have error OPTIONS 405 (Method Not Allowed) when I send data from localhost. pls help me about this.

[Request Method Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A9hB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when you are trying to call some API from another domain. For example, To sent request from 'url1.com' to 'url2.com' you have to set up CORS policy on the server where 'url2.com' is hosted.

As a result, CORS headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods should be sent from your server with each request.

You can read how to do this [here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/enable-cors.html)

Also, you have to enable OPTIONS request to your request (just sent status code 200 on each OPTION request). This thing is called a preflight request. You need to create middleware for it:

```
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {
    if ($request->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS' || php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
        return $next($request, $response);
    }

    $response = $next($request, $response);

    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');    
    return $response;
});
```

Comment: I have read about this. but I dont understand to config. I will would config this code. Is it ?

    <?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;



$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

    $email = $request->getParam('email_login');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $email");

    return $response;
});

Answer (score 0):

I have read about this. but I don't understand to config. I will would config this code. Is it?

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $email = $request->getParam('email_login');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $email");

    return $response;
});
```